# cakephp 2.x using limit in treelist

Tags: php, cakephp

I must use the Treelist because the left, and right fields. I haven't found a way to limit the result because I only need the top element:

```
$lis = $this->Record->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('Record.pnumber' => $id),
    'fields' => array('Record.state_id'),
));

$options = array('NOT' => array('State.id' => $lis));

//How can i use limit here? I only need to get the first element (i have to use the tree structure because the lft field store the arrengment in this case) So 'limit'=>1 but how and where?

$statelists = $this->Record->State->generateTreeList(
    $options, null, null, null, null
);
```

Please I can not use the normal `find('first', $options)` way because I need the tree structure. I have read in the Api that I can use conditions as like by the find, but the limit is not the part of the conditions.

Comment: try adding the limit in the place of the four null place like `$options,null,null,null,limit`

Comment: Please also see https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/6704 - upvote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I forced too much the treelist.Insted of using normal list:

```
$statelists=$this->Record->State->find('list',array(
            'conditions'=>$options,
            'fields'=>array('State.name'),
            'order'=>array('State.lft'),
            'recursive'=>0,
            'limit'=>1
                    )
            );
```